# Error when trying to add Irepositories to services with addScoped ASP.Net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add my Irepository interface and the irepository to the services so I can use them.

I do it like this:

```
services.AddScoped<AuctioniRepository, IrepoAuctionInterface>();
```

And here is the error I get:

> Error CS0311  The type 'NackowskiLillMygel.Data.IrepoAuctionInterface' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'NackowskiLillMygel.Data.IrepoAuctionInterface' to 'NackowskiLillMygel.Data.AuctioniRepository'.    NackowskiLillMygel  source\repos\NackowskiLillMygel\NackowskiLillMygel\Startup.cs   39  Active

I don't understand what I've done wrong.
Also if you need any more code from the repositories please tell me.

I'm very grateful for answers!

Comment: The correct way to add services is `Interface` first then `Class` . So it should be `services.AddScoped<IrepoAuctionInterface, AuctioniRepository>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are registering the interface as the implementation of `IrepoAuctionInterface`. 
The signature of the .AddScoped() method is as following:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services)
    where TService : class
    where TImplementation : class, TService;
```

This means that the `TService` should implement `TImplementation`, you did it the other way around.

You should flip the arguments around like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IrepoAuctionInterface, AuctioniRepository>();
```

Comment: Wow, haha. Thanks dude!
Also another question, if I want to implement another Irepo also, do I just write another AddScoped?

Comment: Generally yes, but you will consume the last registered `IrepoAuctionInterface` in the DI container (so order matters). If you want to consume all registered services you should consume `IEnumerable<IrepoAuctionInterface`.

Comment: If you need access to a specific repository from multiple repositories of the same interface type through the DI container, you'll either have to inject the concrete type you need, or you'll need to implement a factory and inject that instead. The factory pattern is generally a better fit.

Answer (score 3):

Just implement the interface `IrepoAuctionInterface` in the class `AuctioniRepository`

like

```
public class AuctioniRepository : IrepoAuctionInterface
{
}
```